# blasting multiple databases separately

Tags: bash, blast

I am new to bioinformatics. I am trying to find a list of proteins (my query) in over 200 genomes. I want to get the result of each genome separately. I tried to write a bash script but it doesn't work.

I would like it to run 2 tblastn instances at a time only. This code executes over 200 tblastn instances. database_names.txt contains the name of my databases with location.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
   EXT="_results.txt"
   OUTPUT="$line$EXT"
   tblastn -query tf_total.fasta -db $line -out $OUTPUT -outfmt 10 &
done < database_names.txt
```

Here are the first 3 lines of database_names.txt

```
genome1/genome1_blast_db_v1
genome2/genome2_blast_db_v1
genome3/genome3_blast_db_v1
```

Here is the error message

```
Command line argument error: Argument "out". File is not accessible:  
Error: (CArgException::eSynopsis) Too many positional arguments (1), the offending value: _results.csv  
Error: (CArgException::eSynopsis) Application's initialization failed
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.  State specifically what you expect the code to do, and what it is actually doing.  Include the exact wording of any error messages you are getting.

Comment: I added part of the error message. The actual is multiple pages long. Mostly gives me tblastn usage. I am truly confused. I expect this program to run the tf_total.fasta file against all genomes and give a results csv file for each in the same location.

Answer (score 1):

This most likely happens because you have empty lines in `database_names.txt`.

On empty lines, you end up running

```
tblastn -query tf_total.fasta -db -out _result.csv -outfmt 10
```

which I'm sure you'll find gives the same error message.

To alleviate it, skip blank lines and quote your variables:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
   [[ -z $line ]] && continue
   EXT="_results.txt"
   OUTPUT="$line$EXT"
   tblastn -query tf_total.fasta -db "$line" -out "$OUTPUT" -outfmt 10
done < database_names.txt
```

Comment: Hey this does not solve the problem of multiple tblastn starting at the same time. I would prefer if it went 1 or 2 at a time not all 200 at a time. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Your question doesn't state that running multiple instances is a problem. I've updated the code to run one at a time (by removing the `&`).